# Visual Studio 2015 shows "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error on "My Work" tab

Tags: visual-studio-2015

At work, I recently migrated from Visual Studio 2013 to Visual Studio 2015 for the solution I work on. I am now running Visual Studio Enterprise 2015, version 14.0.25420.01 Update 3, and things seem to be working fine for the most part, except as follows:

On my team, we use the built-in Visual Studio code reviews functionality for reviewing our work. When I go to the "My Work" tab, where I'd expect to see the code reviews I currently have submitted, it incorrectly says "No code reviews", and at the top top of the tab, there is a banner that says "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". Likewise, the same banner is displayed whenever a new code review is submitted. Below is a screenshot of the "My Work" tab:

[image: My Work tab]

The code review requests are being sent properly, and I get notified when my reviewer has signed off, but once I've submitted a review I can't return to it. Has anyone else experienced this issue?

Comment: This looks like a bug in Visual Studio. I suggest removing all TFS projects and configuration on your computer, then uninstalling all versions of VS (there is no reason to have a side-by-side install of 2013 and 2015, btw), and then doing a clean reinstall of VS2015 (preferably the one with the Update 3 pre-installed), or even the new VS2017 which is released this week.

Comment: Also it might be an idea to prod your DevOps/Build team and get them to ensure your TFS server is correctly configured/provisioned.

Comment: Thanks, that'll be my course of action if nobody has a simpler fix. I was just hoping this might be one of those things where there's just one file or directory I can delete to clear the behavior rather than setting things back up from scratch.

Comment: If anyone's still curious, I followed the above suggestion and uninstalled all VS versions, then reinstalled only VS2015 with Update 3 - and I'm still having the same issue! I'll update if our configuration folks are able to figure anything out.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found 2 possible solutions:

**1- Migrate to Visual Studio 2017**

It seems odd, but VS 2017 does NOT have the same behavior. The My Work tab opens normally on the same server/collection/project that has the error on VS 2015.

**2- Grant Read and Contribute permissions in Shared Queries to the user facing the problem**

To do that follow the steps bellow:

a. Access http://tfsServer:8080/tfs/collectionName/projectName/_workItems/index (change *tfsServer*, *collectionName* and *projectName* accordingly;

b. Access Shared Queries security submenu;

c. Grant Contribute and Read permissions to the user (or group);

Regards.